# AJAX for Nested Routes Deletes Wrong Object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am attempting to apply AJAX to my to do app and instead of deleting an `item` it is deleting the `list` to which that item belongs.  The code on my `lists#show` page where the items are displayed is as follows. Everything worked before I added the `remote: :true` into things:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <p><%= link_to "", list_item_path(@list, item), method: :delete, remote: :true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', style: "margin-right: 10px" %>    <<<<AJAX MODIFICATION HERE
     <%= item.name %>
    <% if item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id == current_user.id %>
      <small>(Delegated to <%= item.delegated_to %>)</small>
    <% elsif item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id != current_user.id %>
      <small>(Delegated by <%= item.user_id %>)</small>
    <% end %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the `items/destroy.js.erb` file I added:

```
$('#item-<%= @item.id %>').hide();
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it's deleting the list not the item? I'm not too familiar with Javascript.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

```
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
      home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                    home#index
            root GET    /                                        home#index
      list_items GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#index
                 POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#create
   new_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
  edit_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
       list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
                 PATCH  /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                 PUT    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                 DELETE /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
           lists GET    /lists(.:format)                         lists#index
                 POST   /lists(.:format)                         lists#create
        new_list GET    /lists/new(.:format)                     lists#new
       edit_list GET    /lists/:id/edit(.:format)                lists#edit
            list GET    /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#show
                 PATCH  /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#update
                 PUT    /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#update
                 DELETE /lists/:id(.:format)                     lists#destroy
```

Here's the `items#controller` delete section:

```
  def destroy
    @list = List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Item was deleted successfully."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Item couldn't be deleted. Try again."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Console log with `console.log("hello")` test:

[image: Console log]

Comment: probably incorrect route, can you post the route for `list_item_path` in your routes.rb?

Comment: @kasperite, I added the routes to the original post.

Comment: the route is correct though, try replace `remote: :true` to `remote: true` and see if it makes any different?

Comment: Then it doesn't delete anything...

Comment: also your controller ie `items_controller` needs to handle ajax request too, I assume you have done that bit?

Comment: @kasperite, I fixed the post to include the destroy section of the `items_controller`.  In it I fixed an obvious syntax error and now I'm getting `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` on the definition of `@list` in my `show` method of my `lists_controller`: `@list = List.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: again, can't see any issues in the controller except your redirect_to syntax.  What happen if you take out `friendly` scope and just do `List.find(params[:list_id])`

Comment: @kasperite, without that it still does nothing.

Comment: It was working fine before adding  `remote: true ` ? Is it the only thing you changed ? What happens if you change    `@item = @list.items.find(params[:id]) ` to    `@item = Item.find(params[:id]) `  ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick, if I make that change it does delete the item instead of the list, but I still have to manually refresh the page to get the deleted item to disappear.

Comment: @Liz then your destroy.js.erb is wrong ... Add a console.log("hello") in your destroy.js.erb and see if it appears when you delete an item without reloading th page

Comment: @GrahamSlick, I added a screenshot of my console log after putting `console.log("hello")` at the beginning of my .js file.

Comment: Ok so the request does "reach" the controller. To debug, check in your logs (what the rails server command displays after starting the server). When you click on a delete link, you should see an error in your logs. Read carefully it's probably in the middle of a lot of lines

Comment: @GrahamSlick, my logs indicated that it was this error: `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".:`

Comment: @GrahamSlick I made the above edits to remove the redirects from my `items_controller` and now the `log` for the deletion is error free, but the item still isn't disappearing until the page is manually refreshed.

Comment: So The console log appears ?

Comment: No, it has an error on the view that says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help off SO and here's what ended up working:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= div_for(item) do %>
    <p><%= link_to "", list_item_path(@list, item), method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', style: "margin-right: 10px" %>
     <%= item.name %>
    <% if item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id == current_user.id %>
      <small>(Delegated to <%= item.delegated_to %>)</small>
    <% elsif item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id != current_user.id %>
      <small>(Delegated by <%= item.user_id %>)</small>
    <% end %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And:

```
$('#item_<%= @item.id %>').remove();
```